# JQuery form control with radio buttons

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using JQuery with 2 radio buttons to switch between showing and hiding 2 different divs. I also want to be able to check the current value that would be there on a page load (or reload) and set the show/hide status of the divs based on whatever is currently selected.

In other words, do it on a click and if not a click then do whatever its currently set at. I have this code which seems to work fine

```
var type_option = $('input[name=Type]:checked', '#Form').val();
if (type_option == 'A') {
    $("#A").show();
    $("#B").hide();
} else {
    $("#A").hide();
    $("#B").show();         
}
$(".TypeSelect").click(function() {
    type_option = $('input[name=Type]:checked', '#Form').val();
    if (type_option == 'A') {
        $("#A").show();
        $("#B").hide();
    } else {
        $("#A").hide();
        $("#B").show();         
    }
});

<form>
<input type="radio" name="Type" value="A" class="TypeSelect">
<input type="radio" name="Type" value="B" class="TypeSelect">

<div id="A">A Div</div>
<div id="B">B Div</div>
</form>
```

But that just doesn't seem right or at least very optimized. I thought this might work

```
var type_option = $('input[name=Type]:checked', '#Form').val();
$(".TypeSelect").click(function() {
    type_option = $('input[name=Type]:checked', '#Form').val();
});
if (type_option == 'A') {
    $("#A").show();
    $("#B").hide();
} else {
    $("#A").hide();
    $("#B").show();         
}
```

But it didn't, I assume I have to set those divs within the click function? Is there a better way I should be doing this or do I have to do the check and set the divs in both the click and outside the click functions to do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move the logic to a function and then invoke it both on page load and on click event. Something like this.

```
function toggle()
{
    var type_option = $('input[name=Type]:checked', '#Form').val();
    if (type_option == 'A') {
        $("#A").show();
        $("#B").hide();
    } else {
        $("#A").hide();
        $("#B").show();         
    }
}
toggle();
$(".TypeSelect").click(function() {
    toggle();
});
```

Comment: This is some great suggestions in this post, this made the most sense to me though and it does what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".TypeSelect").click(function() {
    if (this.value == 'A') {
        $("#A").show();
        $("#B").hide();
    } else {
        $("#A").hide();
        $("#B").show();         
    }
});
```

Depends on the  initial state of the page, it can even be a lot simpler:

```
$(".TypeSelect").click(function() {
    $('#A, #B').toggle(); // Hide visible element, Show hidden element.
});
```

Comment: I get the click part but its combining that with the initial state. On page load one of the radio buttons will be "checked", I want to make sure the proper div is showing then PLUS I want to do the switch when they click the radio - does that make sense? I like the look of that toggle, I'll try it.

Comment: @Analog. Then hide one div and show the other, check the right checkbox (`checked='checked`) and use the second option to catch radio changes. Don't use javascript to determine what is the initial state of the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Why hide one to show the other why not just set display's to none and do this that way there both not siting there at once

```
<div id="A" style="display: none;">A Div</div>
<div id="B" style="display: none;">B Div</div>

    $(".TypeSelect").click(function() {
        type_option = this.value;
        if (type_option == 'A') {
            $("#A").show();
$("#B").hide();
        } else {
$("#A").show();
            $("#B").show();         
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function togglify(opt) {
  $('div#' + opt).show().siblings('div').hide();  
}
$(".TypeSelect").click(function() {
    type_option = $(this).val();
    togglify(type_option);
}).filter(function() {
    type_option = $(':checked').val();
    togglify(type_option);
});
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pGjcT/2/)***